# Gradle Version for debugging React-Native on Windows using VS Code

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a React-Native app on Windows using VS Code and the React Native Tools extension.  I have my app running in the emulator.  I run the `React Native: Check development environment configuration`

and I see:

```
Info] Starting Environment check...

<<< Dev Environment verification result >>>

*** Common ***
 ✓ Node.JS
 ✓ NPM

*** Android ***
 ✓ ADB
 ✓ Android Emulator
 ✓ Android Env
 ✓ Java
 ✖ Gradle - Requried for building android apps
  Command not found. Make sure Gradle is installed
```

When I go to Android Studio File > Project Structure I see:

[image: Android Studio Screenshot]

I've tried the following in my C:\Users\user\source\TargetSum\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties file:

```
# distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip
#distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.1-all.zip
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

7.5.1 was the version automatically put in the gradle-wrapper.properties file.  I've restarted VS Code after each change, but I see the:

```
✖ Gradle - Requried for building android apps
      Command not found. Make sure Gradle is installed
```

with all 3 versions